# Publish multiple messages in batch processing function with Spring cloud stream Kafka Binder

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am looking for an example to create a functional style processor using spring cloud stream kafka binder (without Kafka Streams) that can consume a batch of n messages from one topic and publish m messages to another topic (m < n).
I have tried the following:

```
public Function<List<IncomingEvent>, List<Message<OutgoingEvent>>> aggregate() {
    return ((batch) -> {
        Map<Key, List<IncomingEvent>> resultsMap = batch.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(result -> IncomingEvent::key));
        List<Message<OutgoingEvent>> aggregationResults = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map.Entry<Key,List<IncomingEvent>> resultGroup : resultsMap.entrySet()) {
            OutgoingEvent outgoingEvent = this.getOutgoingEvent(resultGroup.getKey(), resultGroup.getValue());
            aggregationResults.add(
                MessageBuilder.withPayload(outgoingEvent)
                .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, outgoingEvent.getKey())
                .build() 
            );
        }
        return aggregationResults;
    });
}
```

However, this produces a single event with an array of messages. I tried changing the return type of the function from List<Message> to Flux<Message> and then returning Flux.fromIterable(aggregationResults), and that seems to be publishing multiple messages, but the messages seem to be serialized instances of Flux with properties of scanAvailable and prefetch rather than the actual Message.
I could not find any example of achieving this on the web. Would be very helpful to see such an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's supported; use `Consumer<List<IncomingEvent>>` and use the `StreamBridge` to publish the outbound messages.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.2/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources

**EDIT**

It seems I was wrong; see https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2143

> This is a documentation request. The cloud stream framework supports an undocumented feature to publish a batch of messages using a method signature like `public Function<Whatever, List<Message<POJO>>> myMethod()`. This results in each message in the list being published individually by the binder.

If it's not working for you, I suggest you comment on that issue.

Comment: I added an update - it is supposed to work.

Comment: The batch producing of messages is now documented - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.3-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_batch_producers

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky - As I have mentioned in the github issue (albeit shortly after the issue was resolved), I am not able to reproduce that behaviour at least with spring cloud stream 3.0.1-RC1 and with a binding configured to run in batch mode. However, Gary's suggestion (using stream bridge) works for me and that is why I am marking this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Please use 3.1.2 or 3.1.3-SNAPSHOT as we'll have a release tomorrow anyway